# Why is `:highlight Cursor ...` ignored?

Tags: highlight

My color scheme has:

```
hi Cursor       ctermfg=black   ctermbg=red cterm=NONE
```

This is confirmed using `hi Curosr`:

```
Cursor         xxx ctermfg=0 ctermbg=1 guifg=black guibg=orange
```

However, I'm not getting the desired color in cygwin's mintty.  When the cursor blinks, I get a white back ground with black letters (which is visible enough, since the surrounding text is white on blue).  Unfortunately, it *doesn't* show up well with my `CursorLine` and `CursorColumn` colors.  How can I troubleshoot the cause for my `Cursor` colors being ignored?

Comment: The cursor color is handled by your terminal emulator, not by Vim.

Comment: OK, so does that mean the `Cursor` highlight group is not meaningful for mintty?  Would this be *the* answer to the question?  If so, it might be useful for you to enter it as an answer (just a suggestion).

Comment: I navigated to the mintty options and checked what the foreground, background, and cursor colours were.  Setting the cursor color there seems to work.  Thanks.  Again, feel free to enter your answer as an official answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Playing with the `Cursor` highlight group is a waste of time because the cursor color is handled by your terminal emulator, not by Vim.

Comment: On Cygwin's mintty terminal, the terminal emulator parameters are accessed via the pulldown menu.  Click on the Cygwin icon on the upper left corner of the terminal window and select `Options...`.

Comment: What about the foreground text? Surely vim should know where the cursor is.